get-gke-credentials failed with: required "container.clusters.get" permission(s)
I'm trying to push my Docker images to GCP Artifact Registry and eventually deploy to GKE. Authenticating is going successfully, however, the 'get credentials' step keeps giving me this error:
Error: google-github-actions/get-gke-credentials failed with: required "container.clusters.get" permission(s) for "projects/***/locations/***/clusters/***".
I have given my IAM user the following roles:

Container Analysis Admin
Editor
Kubernetes Engine Admin
Kubernetes Engine Cluster Admin
Kubernetes Engine Cluster Viewer
Kubernetes Engine Developer
Storage Admin


My GitHub workflow yaml file:
name: Deploy to GKE

on:
push:
branches:
- main

jobs:
deploy:
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
steps:
- name: Checkout code
uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Google Cloud CLI and SDK
        uses: google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@v0.3.0
        with:
          service_account_key: ${{ secrets.GCP_SA_KEY }}
          project_id: ${{ secrets.GCP_PROJECT }}
        
      - name: Configure Docker
        run: |
            gcloud --quiet auth configure-docker
    
      - name: Authenticate to GCP
        uses: google-github-actions/auth@v2
        with:
          credentials_json: ${{ secrets.GCP_SA_KEY }}
                  
      - name: Get credentials
        uses: google-github-actions/get-gke-credentials@v2
        with:
          cluster_name: ${{ secrets.GKE_CLUSTER }}
          location: ${{ secrets.GKE_ZONE }}
    
      - name: Build and push Docker images
        run: |
          docker build -t ${{ secrets.GKE_ZONE }}-docker.pkg.dev/${{secrets.GCP_PROJECT}}/reponame/apigateway:latest ./ApiGateway
          docker build -t ${{ secrets.GKE_ZONE }}-docker.pkg.dev/${{secrets.GCP_PROJECT}}/reponame/likeservice:latest ./LikeService

and so on...

name: Apply Kubernetes manifests
run: |
kubectl apply -f K8S/mongo-config.yaml
kubectl apply -f K8S/mongo-secret.yaml
kubectl apply -f K8S/mongo-pv-storage.yaml

and so on...

The GitHub Secrets have been added to the repository.
The cluster is in us-central1-c and the artifact registry in us-central1 (Iowa).
How can this issue be solved?

Consider to ask sys-admin questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Have you checked that the Location and Project are correct? No trailing or white spaces before/after?

does the artifact registry you will be using are in different projects ?

The location and project are correct, no trailing spaces or white spaces. The cluster is in us-central1-c and the artifact registry in us-central1 (Iowa).

@Vercors is the cluster and ACR are in the same project ?

If you're using service account to authenticate and access the ACR and GKE Cluster you must have the following roles/permissions

Artifact Registry Repository Administrator (roles/artifactregistry.repoAdmin)

Kubernetes Engine Cluster Admin (roles/container.clusterAdmin)


This roles should be assigned to the service account on the IAM.

I got auth working using the newer, preferred "Direct Workload Identity Federation" option of google-github-actions/auth. There is no service account involved. It was difficult because the readmes do not tell you enough to get any kubectl commands working (go figure), but hopefully my answer can fill in the gaps - google-github-actions/get-gke-credentials failed with: required "container.clusters.get" permission(s).
The key concept to understand is that you are binding IAM roles to specific scenarios - calls containing specific properties (which can be trusted because they're in tokens from GitHub Actions). You aren't binding roles to users or accounts. This is the key concept that all of the documentation, even the gCloud documentation, fails to establish before explaining all the painful details.
Once you do get it working though, it is nice.
